# Displaying one field of a django form based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django and I've been using it for only 3 months.
I have some groups named sprint 1, sprint 2 etc.
[image]

Every group has a specific user set. What I want to acquire is when a sprint group is selected the user set associated with that sprint group should be shown below so that I could pick an user from the options.

forms.py file

```
class BugForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    info = forms.TextInput()
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = status_choice, widget= forms.Select(),initial="Pending", disabled=True)
    platform = forms.ChoiceField(choices = platform_choice, widget= forms.Select())
    phn_number = PhoneNumberField()
    screeenshot = forms.ImageField()
    assigned_to = ??

    class Meta:
        model = Bug
        fields = ['name', 'info','platform' ,'status', 'assign_sprint', 'phn_number', 'screeenshot']
        widgets = {'assign_sprint': forms.Select()}
```

views.py file

```
class BugUpload(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = 'Login'
    model = Bug
    form_class = BugForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.uploaded_by = self.request.user
        inst = form.save(commit=True)
        message = f"Bug created. Bug id:{inst.bug_id}"
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py file

```
class Bug(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank= False, null= False)
    info = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=status_choice, default="Pending")
    assign_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assigned', blank= True, null= True)
    assign_sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    phn_number = PhoneNumberField()
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='user_name')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank= True, null = True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='updated_user', null = True, blank=True)
    screeenshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices= platform_choice, default="Web")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to update the page after it's been loaded using only Django. You need to use Javascript in order to make a request to the server, and then update the page html depending on server response.